# No operator matches these operands

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(){
  double x1 = 5.25;
  double y1 = 4.2345;
  int nx = 10;
  int ny = 11;
  vector<double> Bn(nx, ny);
  vector<float> x (nx);
  vector<float> y (ny);
  for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
    for (float j = 0; j < 11; j++){
      Bn = exp((pow(x[nx]-x1,2)-pow(y[ny]-y1,2))
    } 
  }
  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I get 'no operator matches these operands c++' error. '=' after Bn is highlighted. I am not sure what I should do. Also is this right way to define an array with unknown size?
I want to be able to define an array where I don't have to define what is in the array.

Q: If I don't define the size of an array, does that mean the compiler will randomly select any numbers or what??

Comment: what do you expect to happen when assigning the result of `exp` to a vector?

Comment: This is not the correct way to make a two-dimensional data structure, if that's your intention. Is it your intention?

Comment: How else would you write an array of data??. I am trying to make a two dimensional data structure. How else would you make a two dimensional data structure??

Answer (score 2):

More than one problem here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
    for (float j = 0; j < 11; j++){
      Bn = exp((pow(x[nx]-x1,2)-pow(y[ny]-y1,2))
    } 
  }
```

You're :

- assigning a `double` to a `std::vector<double>`.
- iterating on `i` and `j` but not using them in the loop.
- accessing an element that exceed the size of your array. Twice `x[nx]` and `y[ny]` whereas `nx` as been used to define the size of `x` and the same for `ny`and `y`.
- missing the `;` at the end of the line `Bn = exp((pow(x[nx]-x1,2)-pow(y[ny]-y1,2))`.

So at least use iterator to walk in your vectors and define where you want to store your output of `exp`.

By the way, as `Bn`as been defined without size, you have to use `Bn.push_back()` to add an element.

Comment: `Bn = exp((pow(x[nx]-x1,2)-pow(y[ny]-y1,2))` won't compile - theres a missing `;` and a missing `)`

Answer (score 2):

To fill a `std::vector` use the function [push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) instead of the assignment operator.
Also there was a missing `)` and a missing `;` in the affected line.

Probably you wanted to use the loop indizes `i & j` inside the `pow()` function instead of the constant values 10 / 11. I hardly guessed what you were trying to do, and came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(){
  double x1 = 5.25;
  double y1 = 4.2345;
  int nx = 10;
  int ny = 11;
  vector<double> Bn(nx, ny);
  vector<float> x (nx);
  vector<float> y (ny);
  /* todo: fill x and y with values */
  for (int i = 0; i <nx; i++){
    for (float j = 0; j < ny; j++){
      Bn.push_back(exp((pow(x[i]-x1,2)-pow(y[j]-y1,2))));
    } 
  }
  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure the OP didn't mean to initialize vector `Bn` with `nx` elements of type `double` giving them all the value `ny`.

Comment: I'm not sure, what he was trying to do... That was the nearest I could guess.

Comment: I make an array of x and y and then calculate Bn to produce an array of results..These two arrays need to have an unknown size.

Comment: @user3087244 Which values do you want to use to initalize the two vectors x and y?

Comment: I would hope to initialise with the value of zero.

Comment: I have tried to use cout << Bn << "Bn" << endl; to see the charts but it wouldn't let me operate